# What skill to use to tell if someone is alive or dead?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Is it Perception to tell if someone is alive after a lot of damage? Or Heal? I checked over Heal, which sounded like it makes sense, but it doesn't actually list anything related to diagnosis or checking someone's condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Heal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/heal) is the skill which will tell you if someone is alive. [Perception](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception) can only tell you they look badly wounded.

I was actually surprised that the heal skill didnt cover this, but as its not actually written down anywhere, my reasoning for it is that the examples covered in perception are about noticing things. You dont have knowledge about it. You can see that a creature is badly injured, but you cant tell if its out or dead. Heal has that extra knowledge, knowing if your effort is needed or not.

Comment: I would add that written adventures use Heal to determine things like cause of death. It seems reasonable to use it as a kind of "would this be fatal" check